# System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred

Tags: arrays, vb6, visual-studio-2013

Trying to make a quick and dirty VB program to rename tif files based on a .dat comma delimited file. Getting this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Here is the code:

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, inFile, strInLine, strOldFile, strNewFile
    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Select the folder
    objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\CKILLION\Desktop\planning commission\")
    'Open Text File
    inFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\CKILLION\Desktop\consct01.dat", 1)
    Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
        'Read text file line by line and Split each line into 4 parts.
        strInLine = Split(inFile.ReadLine, ", ")
        'Old File name
        strOldFile = strInLine(2)
        'new File name
        strNewFile = strInLine(1)
        'Loop through the files in the folder
        For Each File In objFolder.Files
            'If the file name matches the old file name above
            If File.Name = strOldFile Then
                'Replace it
                File.Name = strNewFile
            End If
        Next
    Loop
    'Close the text reader
    inFile.Close()
    MsgBox("Done.")
```

This is some text from the .dat file:

> "1,967","08-26-47","00001875.tif",".\images\00001","54,814","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:13:44am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001875.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,966","09-02-47","00001874.tif",".\images\00001","28,142","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:13:14am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001874.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,965","09-30-47","00001873.tif",".\images\00001","23,342","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:12:40am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001873.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,964","10-14-47","00001872.tif",".\images\00001","38,444","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:12:28am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001872.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,963","10-28-47","00001871.tif",".\images\00001","41,466","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:12:16am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001871.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,962","11-12-47","00001870.tif",".\images\00001","29,560","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:12:00am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001870.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""
>   "1,960","12-03-47","00001868.tif",".\images\00001","36,435","TIFF","9/13/2001 2:11:38am","c:\users\ckillion\desktop\city commission minutes\1947\00001868.tif","City Commission Minutes\1947",""

Comment: how exactly are you using VB6 in VS2013?

Comment: I think it is your Do Until loop. Try to replace it with While loop and see if it helps. Not sure about VB6, but generally Do loops go one more step.

Comment: Thank you. Changed to a Do While loop, still doesn't actually change the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this line with no space in the split where the comma is

```
strInLine = Split(inFile.ReadLine, ",")
```

You have no space between your commas in the line, so the line will not get split because there's no delimiter that matches a comma and space (", ")

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem, I published it and it runs but it doesn't actually change the file names.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you're using. I just recognized the particular problem.

Comment: It's probably a problem with the indices you're trying to access.  When the lines are split with commas, each section between a comma is an index. So wherever the newfile and oldfile strings are, those are the indices you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are trying to access an index that doesn't exists.  It appears that one or more of the lines in your file are not the expected length you think they are.  Without seeing the actual file and knowing where the line breaks are, I can't really help more than that.  I would suggest analyzing the file, ensuring that you have the expected number of fields per line and that no extra commas appear in anything other than where delimitation is occurring.  Hope that helps.